# Displaying data in tables depending on group

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a question in relation to displaying PHP tables that should be straight forward but I cannot get my head around it at the moment so any help would be appreciated, basically what I want to do is display a team of players in a table, but display multiple tables of users with their team name display above it.

What I currently have : http://puu.sh/ilUJp/4a6ae5e47b.png
What I am looking to achieve : http://puu.sh/ilUJ8/7756033517.png

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                <h3>Team Name Goes Here </h3>
   <?php              

echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
echo "  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    ";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $teamName = $row['teamName'];
    $fName = $row['firstName'];
    $surName = $row['surName'];
    echo "
        <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>$teamName</td>
        <td>$fName</td>
        <td>$surName</td>
      </tr>       
    </tbody>

     ";

} 

echo "</table>";
?>
            </div>
```

with my query :

```
$sql = "SELECT t.teamID,t.teamName,u.firstName,u.surName From users as u INNER JOIN team as t where u.teamID = t.teamID  ";
```

I know the idea I need to do but cannot get it done, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add your table structure, It may help us to answer your question. http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
    <?php $teemid=array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          if(!in_array($row['teamID'],$teemid)){
                 array_push($teemid,$row['teamID']);  
             if(!empty($teemid)){ ?>
                   </tbody>
                  </table>       
                </div>
           <?php } 

     ?>
       <div class="col-lg-6">
           <h3><?php echo $row['teamName']; ?></h3>
           <table class='table table-striped'>
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                 </tr>

              </thead>
              <tbody>
             <?php } ?>
              <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row['teamName']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['firstName']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['surName']; ?></td>
             </tr> 


    <?php } ?>
             </tbody>
           </table>       
       </div>
```

**SQL Query Change as below**

```
$sql = "SELECT t.teamID,t.teamName,u.firstName,u.surName From users as u INNER JOIN team as t where u.teamID = t.teamID  ORDER BY u.teamID";
```

Comment: Worked, Thank you very much, I have one issue and that is due to one team having more members, the alignment of the last table is out of line, Is there an easy way to fix it, I thought adding a margin at the bottom of the table would work, but no luck  ? http://puu.sh/ilXFi/825675ffd0.png

Comment: That issue can be occurred because there are different no members for each team. If you need to solve that you should know no of members for team. If you know it balance each team table by adding empty rows (`<tr></tr>`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this logic

```
$teams = "get all teams sql query";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($teams)) {
    $teamid = $row['teamid'];
    $teamname = $row['teamname'];

    $teammemberquery = "select all member in the  where team = $teamid sql query";
    echo "<table>";
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($teammemberquery)) {
        $teamName = $r['teamName'];
        $fName = $r['firstName'];
        $surName = $r['surName'];
        echo "
        <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>$teamName</td>
        <td>$fName</td>
        <td>$surName</td>
      </tr>       
    </tbody>
     ";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try as below (Please replace table column name as yours and mysql to mysqli):**

```
    <?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('test', $link);
$sql = "SELECT t.team_id,t.team,u.fname,u.lname,u.email From users as u INNER JOIN team as t where u.team_id = t.team_id order by t.team_id ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<html><head><title>team</title></head><body><div class="col-lg-6">
    <?php              
        echo "<table>";

        $teamName = "";
        $i=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            if($teamName == "" || $teamName != $row['team'])
            {
                if($i!=0)
                    echo "</table>";

                echo "<tr><td colspan='3'><h3>".$row['team']."</h3></td></tr>";
                $teamName = $row['team'];
                $i=0;
            }
            $fName = $row['fname'];
            $surName = $row['lname'];
            $email = $row['email'];

            if($i==0)
            {
                echo "<table class='table table-striped'><tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                </tr>";
            }

            echo "<tr>
                <td>$fName</td>
                <td>$surName</td>
                <td>$email</td>
                  </tr>";

            $i++;
        } 
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, I have used another solution, but thank you for your time.